# Writing into GStreamer pipeline from OpenCV does not work

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer

I wrote an RTSP server using the gst-rtsp-server library that is using the following pipeline:

```
udpsrc port=8553 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96
```

This outputs just fine in VLC media player when I feed the UDP source through command line:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=800,height=600,codec=h264,type=video ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8553
```

Instead of using the videotestsrc I want to read from webcam and process the image using OpenCV with GStreamer in Python. I have built OpenCV from source with GStreamer support.

Unfortunately this does not work:

```py
import cv2
import numpy

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Identical to command line pipeline but using appsrc
output = cv2.VideoWriter('appsrc ! video/x-raw,width=800,height=600,codec=h264,type=video ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8553', 0, 30, (800, 600))

while capture.isOpened():
    retval, frame = capture.read()

    if retval:
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        output.write(frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1):
            break
    else:
        break

capture.release()
output.release()
```

I am not getting any errors, but VLC does not display anything either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your caps for `appsrc` are:

```
appsrc ! video/x-raw,width=800,height=600,codec=h264,type=video !
```

Which means you are pushing `appsrc` to output a h264 video. In OpenCv `appsrc` only outputs raw BGR frames. Taking out this caps would be sufficient to make it work.

'appsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8553'

**Hint:** Gstreamer has verbosity levels. You can see the errors produced by gstreamer by changing the verbosity level of gstreamer.

You can do this with as such:

```
GST_DEBUG=3 python my_script.py
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, unfortunately it did not fix the issue. I have changed the verbosity level to 3 as you suggested, its prints this on the server-side: https://pastebin.com/raw/xGMFke2R

Comment: Do you have any other idea?

Comment: I'm verry sorry, my network doesn't allow me to open pastebin. Could you share your log somewhere else?  (https://gist.github.com/ maybe)

Comment: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/marcelherd/7b0f70d40b91da9725db2bd92ef64f1a/raw/33aae53193b9ab9c28109f4594aec706e7d7aa0b/Log.txt

Comment: I was able to fix the issue of no data being sent by adding host to udpsink and address to udpsrc. I get a different error now with libav being unable to decode because the timestamps are backwards. Do you happen to know how to fix this? http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/libav-error-while-decoding-MB-td4692487.html

Comment: I'm not sure but, could it be that you need to set an alignment caps for your x264enc and udpsrc element such as `alignment=(string)au` or `alignment=(string)nal`